# Resharper C++: How to disable blue "? Use macro" popup box?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I have a problem with the Resharper C++ Plugin vor Visual Studio 2013

It keeps popping up this blue information box as seen in the picture below.

[image]

The problem is that my cursor is on line 91 and not on line 94 for which the box is displayed. The code in line 93 is completly hidden by that box which persistently reappears when I click on other lines.

I tried to find the switch in the options that turns off that blue box, but I was not able to find it. Can anybody point me to the option that removes the box?

Comment: Try hitting the "escape" key.

Comment: This hides the box, but I would prefer it never to pop up in the first place, because I don't even know what help it is supposed to provide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also try unticking the checkbox in ReSharper | Options | Code Inspection | Settings | Show the 'Import Namespace' action using popup

Comment: I currently can not reproduce the problem because my code changed so I can not verify your answer. But I have goog faith and mark this as the correct answer anyways.

Comment: I now can say that the answer really works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As for Resharper 2021.3.2 the setting moved to the the location ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | Type Import | Show the 'import missing references' popup in editor.